# How to mitigate insecure password policy that I am forced to use?

Tags: passwords, password-policy, threat-mitigation

The site in question is the UK regulator for companies at https://ewf.companieshouse.gov.uk. Online access to a company on this site enables the user to file/change various critical things on behalf of the company including the name, address, owners, directors, annual accounts, etc. The public records that these generate are often relied upon by external institutions such as banks. A successful attacker can therefore potentially take over a company and its assets.

**The security policy consists of this:**

1. You first login to the site with a **site account** by supplying an email address and password. However, this should be considered irrelevant because *any* site account can proceed to step 2 - there is no correlation between site accounts and company accounts. To put it another way, step 1 can be bypassed by simply registering a new site account and logging in with that.
2. You then login to a **company account** by supplying a company number (which is publicly available information) and an authentication code. To reiterate, *any site account can login to any company account*. As far as I can tell, a site account serves no purpose other than to get you to the company account login screen.
3. The policy is somewhat opaque but as far as I can tell from experimenting, the authentication code consists of exactly 6 characters, and can only be made up of capital letters and numbers. This means there are 36^10 = 2,176,782,336 possible codes.
4. The initial authentication code is sent to the registered address of the company by snail mail.
5. The code can be changed, but a copy of the new code is again sent out by snail mail.

**Risks:**

1. Poor password selection criteria.
2. Plaintext storage of the password.
3. Exposure of the password whilst in transit in the post.

**Further assumptions:**

- Asking the regulator to change their policy is likely to be a waste of time (unless someone knows a legal route to force the issue).
- The regulator is a monopoly so there is no possibility to take my "business" elsewhere.
- It is possible to deregister an authentication code, but this is even less secure as the company can then be managed by post, with no security checks at all (i.e. the regulator will accept at face value anything it receives in the post). Having online access prevents this for certain types of filings.

Given the above, what steps should I take to mitigate the risks? My plan so far includes frequent code changes, checking the mail for signs of tampering, and shredding the letters upon receipt. On the other hand, I wonder if this may be a case where changing the code is more harmful than useful, as it increases the chances of it being exposed in the post.

Comment: Is the code tied to the account? Can I use your company's code using my account?

Comment: @schroeder No, there is no connection between a code and an "account" (of the type described in point 1 in the question). There are effectively two types of account: Account A is logged into with an email address and password. Anyone can register an Account A. Account B is logged into with a company number and an authentication code. You need to be logged into an arbitrary Account A to be reach the screen where you log into Account B, but any Account A can then login to any Account B, provided they have the authentication code.

Comment: 1: The 6 character password is within the best practices, because it was selected by the service rather than the user. (This means it's more likely to be chosen randomly, and very unlikely to be reused, which _greatly_ mitigates attempts to guess it, so while user generated passwords are "good enough" starting at 8 characters, service generated passwords are good enough at 6 characters.) 2: There is no evidence that the password is stored in plaintext. Only transmitted in plaintext. 3: Sending it through post adds a layer of authentication, and is no less secure than many out-of-band channels.

Comment: As for how you can mitigate it, I assume that you have some way to petition the various bodies of your government.  In the US, there is a Freedom of Information Act Request, which if applied in your situation (obviously it doesn't, but I'm hoping there's a similar method) could be used to request a list of times that the password had been reset, which could provide evidence of attempt of fraud, which you could then work with the regulators to protect your interests _with evidence that someone is attacking you_.

Comment: @Ghedipunk 1. Agreed for the *initial* code, but this is negated by the fact that the same restriction applies to user created codes. 2. I didn't add this to the question, but it is possible at any time to ask them to post you a reminder of your authentication code (thus confirming they are stored in plaintext). 3. I again agree insofar as the *initial* code is concerned, but sending a copy in the post adds nothing of value (and adds a security risk) for subsequent changes of the code by the user.

Comment: @Ghedipunk Generally, initial passwords are treated as fairly insecure (hence justifying sending them out-of-band) on the expectation that the user will subsequently change them to one of their own choosing. It is that scenario that my question mainly relates to.

Comment: If you think it is a significant and realistic threat to your business, then work with them to demonstrate a plausible security flaw, and tell them that you're going public with it after 90 days whether they fix it or not. (Look up "responsible disclosure"). You definitely want lawyers involved, and you want to work with their customer service and security teams sitting next to you while you demonstrate it to them.  (Then again, your risk assessment may show that it will be cheaper and more productive to spend your time tending to your business.)